# when i created a class and calling the method created in that class, i am facing error, its redirecting two time in function and showing nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, rest

i am working on Rest API with Swift IOS coding. my problem is when i am requesting the data from controller its working but the when i created a class and calling the method created in that class, i am facing error, its redirecting two time in function and showing nil.

my class request function is:

```
func MakeRequestToServer(url:String, httpMethod:String, parameters: String) -> (NSURLResponse, NSData, NSError) {

    var responseValue = NSURLResponse()
    var dataValue = NSData()
    var errorValue = NSError()

    var URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
    request.HTTPMethod = httpMethod

    let stringConversionToBase64 = "testu"
    let base64Data = stringConversionToBase64.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64String = base64Data?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
    request.setValue(base64String!, forHTTPHeaderField:"customerKey")

    request.setValue("127.0.0.1", forHTTPHeaderField:"clientIpAddress")

    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    request.HTTPBody = parameters.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        {
            (response, data, error) in

            responseValue = response
            dataValue = data
            // errorValue = error

            println("respo\(response)")
            // println("json from server: \(json)")

    }
    return (responseValue,dataValue,errorValue)
}
```

and from the controller i am calling this method is like...

```
 var repso = MakeRequestToServer(finalURL, requestType, postString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it returns `nil`s. You are returning at the end before the asynchronous request is completed. Refactor this function to use `completionHandler`. Tip:

```
func makeRequestToServer(url: String, httpMethod: String, parameters: String, completionHandler: ((data: NSData?, error: NSError?)->())) {
    //
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response, data, error) -> Void in
        //
        completionHandler(data: data, error: error)
    }
}
```

Comment: response in login: (nil, Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."

Comment: @GopalRohila It means you've got request timeout. I have no idea what you're trying to connect to.